# Setting a serverside session object in javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session-variables

I searched SO and google, but did not find anything that would resolve my issue.
I have a popup window where the user can click "Save", "Delete" or "Close". Each of these three functions will eventually close the popup window. On the parent window codebehind, I need to know which of the 3 buttons the user clicked.

Currently, on the popup window (if the user clicks Delete), I have (pre-existing code) :

```
function CloseDelete() {

    var agree = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
    if (agree)
        __doPostBack("<%=btnDelete.UniqueID %>", "");
    // create session object here //
    else
        return false;

    GetRadWindow().Close();
}
```

I was thinking of creating a session object in javascript on the popup window, which I could check on the parent window codebehind. How would I create a session object in the function above ? Or how can I determine which button the user clicked?